# Boolean property in Puppet provider

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am writing a Puppet provider and I need a boolean property. I declared it with:

```
newproperty(:no_sync, :boolean => true) do
  desc "Whether to omit syncing the file after every logging, ony when action_type is file."
end
```

Then I need to declare the `no_sync` function in the provider which should return `true` or `false`. However, when I do this, it seems the values returned as not properly interpreted by Puppet. I've tried returning strings (`:true` and `:false` respectively), but as a result they always get interpreted as true (which is quite logical).

How are we supposed to declare boolean properties in a Puppet provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning the symbols `:true` and `:false` from the provider method is the correct thing to do.

You could take a look at the [macauthorization source code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/2.7.19/lib/puppet/type/macauthorization.rb#L57-69) for an example of how the type is defined.  The provider for this type returns `:true` or `:false`.

Comment: Do I have to test for `no_sync == :true` then?

Comment: That works great, thank you! (And sorry for the delay in testing your solution.)